# Need help parsing two sentences

Tags: syntactic-analysis

For work, I need to pass a parsing test, but I'm very confused.

Here are the examples I was given of how to do it:

> We / have searched / far and wide / for / real-world / video content.

> Selecting / a / part of speech / can / be / tricky.

So, how would you parse these two sentences?

> Though the video was reposted and grabbed tons of eyeballs over the past week, it turns out to be a more low-resolution version of a video that previously went viral earlier this year.

> One of the pleasures of these videos is that they reverse the more common scenario of young people befuddling the old with their newfangled technology—for once, the old people get to be the in-the-know party here.

Comment: What is the specific question?

Comment: This is not grammatical parsing. This looks like breaking up the written text into speech groups, rather roughly, as if to make it easier to read aloud, particularly by an inexperienced and/or foreign reader.

Comment: Without explaining what the / are supposed to divide up it is impossible to say how they would be applied to the more complex sentences. The two examples given aren't sufficient to infer the rules that placed the /.

Comment: @AlanMunn I’d exactly right- there’s not enough information.

Comment: @JohnLawler That's exactly what it is. I need to do this test for a language learning platform, and they've asked me to parse these complex sentences with no more indications than those two examples....

Comment: @AlanMunn and Jim thank you for your input. That's exactly what I was thinking. I've been doing lots of research and becoming frustrated by not understanding what I should do..